# Update brightway without changing project

Tags: brightway

while working with brightway2 I realized my version was not up to date and tried to update it using `conda update brightway2` but it would not do it.
I have to set a new project and update brightway2 in this new project to have the latest version running.
My question is simple: is there a way to update brightway2 without having to create a new project?

Comment: Do you mean that you want to update the list of methods and exchanges that were imported when running bw2setup()?

Comment: Yes i meant update the methods and exchanges and not update brightway itself. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you have updated brightway data, running `bw.bw2setup()` in a new project will give you the most up-to-date methods and biosphere exchanges.
You cannot run `bw.bw2setup()` in a project where `bw.bw2setup()` has already been run. This is simply because the `biosphere3` database already exists.

Let's suppose you imported brightway2 as bw:

```
`import brightway2 as bw
```

To update your biosphere exchanges, you first need to delete your existing biosphere3 database:

```
bw.Database('biosphere3').delete()
bw.Database('biosphere3').deregister()
```

If you run `bw2setup()` now, you will not update your methods, though - brightway will complain about the methods you are trying to save already existing, and quit. I have not found a way to delete the methods using brighway2 methods, but simply deregistering them works:

```
all_method_tuples = list(bw.methods)
for m in all_method_tuples:
    bw.Method(m).deregister()
```

Now you are ready to import your biosphere exchanges and methods:

```
`bw.bw2setup()
```

Answer (score 1):

Updating Brightway (or any other Python library) doesn't really have anything to do with which project you are in. If you are on Windows, you need to activate your conda environment (usually `activate <some-name>`), and then you can run `conda update -c conda-forge -c cmutel -c haasad brightway`.

After updating, any running scripts or iPython kernels should be restarted.